# Runtime compilation of HashSet<T>

Tags: c#, hashset

I am trying to compile this code in runtime. But I am getting compilation error.
If I copy-paste generated code to Visual Studio, it is compiling without problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Evaluator
{
  public static class Evaluator
  {
    public static bool Run()
    {
        int number = 100;
        var hashSet = new HashSet<int> { 909, 910, 911, 912 };
        if (hashSet.Contains(number)) return true;

        // Code simplified

        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I am compiling

```
var parms = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = false,
            GenerateInMemory = true,
            IncludeDebugInformation = false
        };
        // parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add()
        CodeDomProvider compiler = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

        var assembly = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parms, str).CompiledAssembly;
```

If I change `HashSet` to `Dictionary` it is compiling without problem.

Comment: `HashSet<>` is defined in the `System.Core` assembly, not in `mscorlib`... It could be for this reason.

Comment: @xanatos, I created new project in VS and removed reference to `System.Core` and copied above code to this project. It is compiling and running there.

Comment: @xanatos create an answer..

Comment: Just a general hint, if you encounter an exception you should allways provide it in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some references to some assemblies:

```
// Add these two lines
parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");

// This line is yours
CodeDomProvider compiler = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
```

Interestingly, if I compile and I output a dll, instead of compiling in memory, like:

```
parms.GenerateInMemory = false;
parms.OutputAssembly = "OutputAssembly.dll";
```

I don't need to add a reference to `System.dll`. Fun :-)